# PHP How to use ssh function with only a private key

Tags: php, ssh

I'm looking to connect to a server using ssh. I read in the documentation that I also need to specify the public key.

```
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file ( resource $session , string $username , string $pubkeyfile , string $privkeyfile [, string $passphrase ] ) : bool
```

Is it possible to ommit the pub key?

Also I would like to pass the value of the private file instead of the path to the file

Comment: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssh-tutorial-how-does-ssh-work

Comment: PuTTY is an SSH and telnet client, developed originally by Simon Tatham for the Windows platform. PuTTY is open source software that is available with source code and is developed and supported by a group of volunteers.

Comment: @Marcin why do I need to specify the public key also ?

Comment: I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH is based on [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) approach. In such a system, any person can encrypt a message using the receiver's public key, but that encrypted message can only be decrypted with the receiver's private key.

Therefore you need to use two keys for the communication here: public key for the server to be able to encrypt returned data and at the same time you must habe your private key so you can decrypt what server encrypted. And you must it your private key private otherwise anyone would be able to decrypt the data, making whole effort futile.